# Referencing a span element with an eval

Tags: javascript

I have a function that references an `input` and changes it's value accordingly with the final line:

```
eval('document.forms[0].telephone').value = $telephone[$i];
```

However, I need to move what is displayed in to a `span`, and need to correctly reference it. Currently, the `input` has a `name` and an `id` of "country", and I believe my `eval()` is referencing the `name`.

My span doesn't have a `name`, and instead has a class `tel-prefix`.

I've tried to reference it the following ways (and many combinations thereof), and none work:

```
eval('document.forms[0].tel-prefix').value = $telephone[$i];
eval('.tel-prefix').value = $telephone[$i];
eval('.tel-prefix').text= $telephone[$i];
$('.tel-prefix').value = $telephone[$i];
$('.tel-prefix').value($telephone[$i]);
```

How would I get my `eval()` to change the value of my `span`?

**Full JS**

```
$telephone = new Array(4)
$telephone  [0] = "+93"
...
$telephone  [246] = "+260"
$telephone  [247] = "+263"

function getTelephone($selectedIndex) {
    $selectBox = document.forms[0].spch_country;
    if ($selectBox.options[$selectedIndex].value != 'none') {
        for ($j = 0, $i = $selectedIndex; $i < $selectedIndex + 1; $j++, $i++) {
            eval('document.forms[0].tel-prefix').value = $telephone[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just a suggetion better to not use `eval`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't my code. I don't even know what an `eval` really is!

Comment: The eval you're using just returns the element... You could just drop eval from around it and access the node directly... Also eval ('.class') does not return something like that. try $(".tel-prefix") ...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Can you show the full javascript code?

Comment: I don't see any use of `eval` this should work there `document.forms[0].tel-prefix.value = $telephone[$i];`

Comment: With that instead, I get the error `Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: @Mritunjay: You can't use `tel-prefix` as an identifier, so you would need to use a string as in `document.forms[0]["tel-prefix"].value`, but that only works if the element is a field in that form, which a span tag isn't.

Comment: @Guffa ya sure I dind't noticed the hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that use of `eval` is completely unwarranted, as there is nothing that needs to be evaluated that way. The original code should have been just:

```
document.forms[0].telephone.value = $telephone[$i];
```

The `eval` function evaluates a string as code, which is generally associated with risks of [cross site scripting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and similar. Accessing elements using `eval` is actually never needed, even with dynamic field names they can be accessed by name without using `eval`. Example:

```
var formNumber = 0;
var fieldName = "telephone";
document.forms[formNumber][fieldName].value = $telephone[$i];
```

---

Back to the `span`; in modern browsers you can use the [`querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to find it using the class name. Then you use the `innerHTML` property to set the content:

```
document.querySelector('.tel-prefix').innerHTML = $telephone[$i];
```

To work in older browsers it would help a lot if you can add an id to the span (for example `id="telPrefix"`), then you can use the `getElementById` method:

```
document.getElementById('telPrefix').innerHTML = $telephone[$i];
```

It's possible to find the element using the class name, but then you need to loop through all elements in the page until you find it in browsers that doesn't support the `querySelector` method.